# convert pandas dataframe columns to dictionary

Tags: pandas, dataframe

What is the best way to group by a dataframe column and build a dictionary of another two columns. Here is the dataframe:

```
data = {"name": ["king", "king", "king", "queen", "queen", "queen", "jack", "jack", "jack"],
       "subject": ["maths", "science", "english", "maths", "science", "english","maths", "science", "english"],
       "marks": ["100", "93", "98", "88", "76", "90", "77", "56", "92"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by _"the best way to group"_. It would be nice if you could add some details about this.

Answer (score 1):

Group on `name`, use `apply` to build the `dict`, and reset the index:

```
df = (
    df.groupby("name")
    .apply(lambda x: dict(zip(x["subject"], x["marks"])))
    .reset_index(name="Marks")
)
```

```
    name                                              Marks
0   jack  {'maths': '77', 'science': '56', 'english': '92'}
1   king  {'maths': '100', 'science': '93', 'english': '...
2  queen  {'maths': '88', 'science': '76', 'english': '90'}
```

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>pandas 2.2.1</kbd>

We can take advantage of the fact that `pandas.Series` can be used as a mapping when creating dictionaries. For example, the code `dict(pandas.Series(data=[1,2,3], index=[*'abc']))` will produce the dictionary `{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}`.

At first, we have to set `'subject'` as an index before grouping by `'name'` so that subjects would later become keys. Then we aggregate the reindexed grouped data using `dict` as the aggregation function for the remaining columns (columns retain their names):

```
df.set_index('subject').groupby('name').agg(dict)
```

Output:

```
>>> print(df.set_index('subject').groupby('name').agg(dict).to_string())

                                                    marks
name                                                     
jack    {'maths': '77', 'science': '56', 'english': '92'}
king   {'maths': '100', 'science': '93', 'english': '98'}
queen   {'maths': '88', 'science': '76', 'english': '90'}
```

Whether it is worth resetting `'name'` from an index to a regular column depends on the further objectives.

---

*P. S.*

Suppose we want to keep information about each subject, even if there is no record of it for some person. In this case, we can do the same trick as before, but after pivoting:

```
df.pivot(index='subject', columns='name').apply(dict).unstack(0)
```

We put `'subject'` to index so that `apply(dict)` transform data in columns into a dictionary as previously. We skip the `value` parameter when pivoting, so all remaining column names are stored at the 0 level in the output series index and returned as column names with `unstack(0)`

Let's drop the first record to see how it works:

```nont
>>> print(df.drop(0).pivot(index='subject', columns='name').apply(dict).unstack(0).to_string())

                                                   marks
name                                                    
jack   {'english': '92', 'maths': '77', 'science': '56'}
king    {'english': '98', 'maths': nan, 'science': '93'}
queen  {'english': '90', 'maths': '88', 'science': '76'}
```

As you can see, the king's dictionary has the entry `'maths': nan`, which wouldn't be there if we had done things the way we did before.

Comment: This is a really nice solution. Consider including the output